# Start Elixir Task after Completion of another Task

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

Please Using the `Task` Module, what's the best approach in starting Task Y after Task X has completed  or after x Seconds of Task X Starting?

Comment: Why don't you just do something like `A.do_something; :timer.sleep(2000); B.do_another_thing`

Comment: @Sheharyar, Would that run the Task asynchronously in the background while other processing continues?

Comment: No but you could wrap two different method calls in a single `Task` with `:timer.sleep` between them. Both of them will be executed asynchronously, with X seconds between them.

Comment: @Sheharyar, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement to start Y either when X finishes or after 5 seconds, you should use a message to signal task Y and give Y a timeout. This should do the trick:

```
defmodule Schedule do
  def run do
    IO.puts "running it..."
    spawn &task1/0
  end

  def task1 do
    pid = spawn &task2/0

    # do your work here
    IO.puts "working on task 1"
    :timer.sleep 6_000
    send pid, :start
    IO.puts " task 1 done"
  end

  def task2 do
    receive do
      :start -> :ok
      after 
        5_000 ->  :ok
    end
    # do your work here
    IO.puts "working on task 2"
  end
end
```

You could use Tasks too, but not really needed for a simple case.